# What is application of latch in VLSI design?

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, latch, rtl

I went through the documents stating difference between latch and flip flop. I even came across the scenarios where unintentional latches are created in RTL designs.

My doubt is there any real application for latch?

Comment: Nah, they're totally useless.  Never would we ever have to save a digital value that only appears for a short time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To realize the point of a latch, consider that a flip flop is two back to back latches with opposite polarity clocks.  This forms a lock-and-dam system which causes the output to change one cycle after the input (assuming setup and hold conditions are met).

So, the in->out path of a flip flop 'crosses' the cycle boundary.  A circuit bound by flip flops will require two cycles for an input to show up at the output.  If you only have a single cycle, you need to use a latch-bound circuit.  This is essentially spreading out the two latches which comprise the flip flop and stuffing logic in between, instead of on either side (and causes the delay from input to output to be one cycle).

Below is an example of "spreading the flip flop" into its separate latches for a single cycle circuit:

[image: latch based design]

Latches by themselves also allow much more flexibility in their usage.  They allow "time-borrowing" which is a very powerful concept used all the time in VLSI design.  In contrast, a standard flip flop only allows "time-stealing".

Below is a time-borrowing example with latches

[image: latch-time borrowing]

And time-stealing with a flip flop:

[image: time stealing with ff]

On top of that, latches are almost exclusively used as the storage elements for clock or power gating circuits; they require less area/power than a flip-flop and accomplish the required job of storing a value (enable signal generally) across a half-cycle boundary.

As one further note, latches are often used in a way that mimics the flip-flop behavior.  This is done by pulsing the clock very quickly; just long enough for whatever data is at the input to show up at the output, and not much longer.  In this configuration, they are called [pulse latches, as described by IEEE](http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1271447)

Answer (score 1):

In many cases an increase in the throughput of a digital circuit is required, but for some reasons you cant build a pipelined version. So you end up building a pseudo-pipelined version of this circuit.

A pseudo-pipelined version of a circuit might contain latches. For example if i want to double the throughput of this digital module **A**

[image]

We can build the following *pseudo-pipelined* circuit [That include latches] to double the throughput

[image]

Every two clock cycles, one of the latchs output is changed with a new output allowing its A module to compute a valid result within this time. The new pseudo-pipelined version doubles the throughput without missing with the internal structure of A itself. So you might find latches in circuits like this

Comment: "The new pseudo-pipelined version doubles the throughput without missing with the internal structure of A itself." How exactly? In both cases date per clock is only one.

Comment: @tollinjose Well if an instance of A has a Tpd = 10ns, in a pseudo-pipelined version your clock width will probably be half of this since we have two instances running. [at T=0 latch the 1st input in the upper instance .. at T=5 latch the 2nd input in the lower instance .. at T=10 latch the 3rd input in the upper instance since it has already finished calculating the 1st input]. you are completely right this is still one data/clk **BUT** the clock width is halfed since you have two instances of the same module running at the same time.